# Npm script run client-side JS before server-side NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a NodeJS script that needs to get the devices' screen size. I've found an npm package that does this, but since it gets the screen dimensions using the `window` object, I cannot include it in the NodeJS script.

Is there a way to define an npm script (defined in package.json as something like `"run": "npm run getDimensions.js | node index"`) that will run the clientside JS to get screen dimensions, then pipe the height and width to the serverside NodeJS, or save it to a configuration file, or something?

Comment: You can't really get the dimensions at build time - you're basically running code on two different computers, the one with the browser and the one on the server.  Your client code will need to pass the screen information as part of API calls to your node code if the back-end needs it.  But not sure why server-side code would need to have knowledge of the screen dimensions... that feels like a code smell.